# Java Beginner: embeddable SQL clients with front end GUI,

Tags: java, sqlclient

I'm looking for Java SE embeddable sql clients with there GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)